# RSK node on an Apple M1 chip architecture?

Tags: apple-m1, apple-silicon, rsk

Following [these instructions](https://developers.rsk.co/quick-start/step1-install-rsk-local-node/)
to install the RSK node on an 2021 MBP with Apple M1 Pro chip.
I would like to run an RSK node locally in `regtest` mode.
After installation, running the command to start RSKj:

```sh
java \
  -classpath ~/.rsk/rskj-core-3.1.0-IRIS-all.jar \
  -Drpc.providers.web.cors=\* \
  -Drpc.providers.web.ws.enabled=true \
  co.rsk.Start \
  --regtest
```

... results in the following error:

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no leveldbjni in java.library.path, /private/var/folders/40/k7t383452q75nkmr_5kl12_80000gn/T/libleveldbjni-64-8276576211622720497.jnilib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/40/k7t383452q75nkmr_5kl12_80000gn/T/libleveldbjni-64-8276576211622720497.jnilib, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/40/k7t383452q75nkmr_5kl12_80000gn/T/libleveldbjni-64-8276576211622720497.jnilib' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,i386', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libleveldbjni-64-8276576211622720497.jnilib' (no such file)]
        at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:182)
        at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:140)
        at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory.<clinit>(JniDBFactory.java:48)
        at org.ethereum.datasource.LevelDbDataSource.init(LevelDbDataSource.java:104)
        at org.ethereum.datasource.LevelDbDataSource.makeDataSource(LevelDbDataSource.java:70)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildTrieStore(RskContext.java:1031)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildAbstractTrieStore(RskContext.java:951)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.getTrieStore(RskContext.java:408)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildRepositoryLocator(RskContext.java:1073)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.getRepositoryLocator(RskContext.java:384)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.getTransactionPool(RskContext.java:353)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildInternalServices(RskContext.java:844)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.buildNodeRunner(RskContext.java:836)
        at co.rsk.RskContext.getNodeRunner(RskContext.java:302)
        at co.rsk.Start.main(Start.java:34)
```

Looks like the most likely problem is an incompatibility of something within RSKj with my chip architecture.
Is there a workaround that will allow RSKj to run with an M1 chip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, the problem is with the `leveldbjni` dependency, which is not running on `aarch64` architecture. However, one can get around this limitation by running RSK node in a Docker container.
This process is described in detail in the [Docker installation instructions](https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/node/install/docker/) on the RSK devportal.

Summary:

You can install Docker running

```sh
brew install --cask docker
```

Register a free Docker account, login to your installed desktop app and then in the terminal run

```sh
docker run rsksmart/rskj-standalone
```

Then you should download `Dockerfile.RegTest` and `supervisord.conf` from [artifacts repo](https://github.com/rsksmart/artifacts/tree/master/Dockerfiles/RSK-Node) and in the same folder execute:

```sh
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t regtest -f Dockerfile.RegTest .
```

When the build finishes, you have a container ready to run RSK. To run the container, you should execute

```sh
docker run -d --name regtest-node-01  -p 4444:4444 -p 30305:30305 regtest
```

Now your local test RSK node will be running ready for testing your smart contracts.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use Rosetta to run x86 code on M1. Just add `arch -x86_64` at the begin of your command.

```
arch -x86_64 java \
  -classpath ~/.rsk/rskj-core-3.1.0-IRIS-all.jar \
  -Drpc.providers.web.cors=\* \
  -Drpc.providers.web.ws.enabled=true \
  co.rsk.Start \
  --regtest
```

Comment: arch: posix_spawnp: java: Bad CPU type in executable

Comment: is there a way to "install" the `86_64` arch type for rosetta?

Comment: Install Rosetta from command line: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`
More information: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable